# Get SharePoint group names with Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to get the SharePoint security groups at site collection/site level with Graph API? I have followed [Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/sharepoint) article by MS but no where they mentioned about pulling information from security groups. I want to use this Graph API url in my power apps to apply role based security.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to interact SharePoint's own user or group resource via Microsoft Graph at the moment. For the time being you would need to use the classic [SharePoint REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx) (i.e. `/_api/web/siteusers`) for this.

Comment: How to combine power apps and REST queries?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not very familiar with PowerApps. I'd suggest posting a separate question to that community.